# Waht is wrong with my @DataMongoTest - throwing org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Hi I am using MongoDB transaction feature with Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE version. I am getting the following exception. I am writing the integration test with the controller classes.

Exception given below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.app.cat.resource.Test0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'controller'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dell.pde.resources.NVTValidationCategoryController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPost
```

I provide below the code snippet.

```
@Profile("test")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = MongoDBTxnConfiguration.class)
@Import(TestMongoConfig1.class)

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, RedisAutoConfiguration.class,
    RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,  
    SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.cat"})
public class Test0 {
    
    @Autowired
    private CategoryController controller;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validations")
    private ValidationService vldnService;
    
    @Test
    void testAllValidationsBeforeEntry() {
        System.out.println("controller : " + vldnService);
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@DataMongoTest` annotation also uses `@AutoConfigureDataMongo`, `@ImportAutoConfiguration`. If you provide autoconfigured classes, it will conflict. You have to use `@DataMongoTest` to exclude other classes to load and run. Since it is a Test class, do not use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.cat"})`. Finally I provide the bit code snippet which may be helpful to you.

```
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, 
        SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, 
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ... <any other configuration>})
@Profile("test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app.cat"}, excludeFilters={
          @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, 
                  value= {MongoDBTxnConfiguration.class,SecurityCloudConfig.class})})

public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private YourControler ctrlr;
    
    
    @Test
    void test1() {
        // Logic for testing
    }
}
```